# how to set height to GridFieldManager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How do I set a specific height to a `GridFieldManager` in BlackBerry?

Can anyone give sample code for it?

I get the data from xml and add it to a `GridFieldManager` but I want to set the height of the `GridFieldManager` and give it a SCROLLBAR.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GridFieldManager-USE-ALL-HEIGHT-USE-ALL-WIDTH/td-p/519007 look at this link

Answer (score 1):

I would just put `GridFieldManager` inside `VerticalFieldManager`:

```
VerticalFieldManager container = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
...
GridFieldManager grid =...
...
container.add(grid);
add(container);
```

And after set height for your `container` instead of `grid`.